# Print WordPress API Call on Page/Post

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl

I am attempting to print the following sentence between content on an existing WP page/post using the following code:

"This is based on 38 reviews with an average score of 4.9."
"This is based on  reviews with an average score of  4.9.

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      const url = "https://api.yotpo.com/products/Q6IzQniPhEwgOfDx2C58uKPy5G2OgNnZtPpQpfWI/4379928772/bottomline";

  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      const data = json.body; // json.response maybe, if it uses that format
      const avg = data.bottomline["average_score"];
      const numReviews = data.bottomline["total_reviews"];
      p.textContent = `This is based on ${numReviews} with an average score of ${avg}`;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      alert("The reviews could not be loaded!");
      console.error(err.message);
    });
</script>
```

I'm still not able to get this to work properly; some help would be appreciated.

Comment: We need a bit more code from you. For example, there's a `p` variable that hasn't been defined yet (at least not in the code provided by you). Also, you need to know the id/class of the container where you want to inject this message.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k1rntao7/

Comment: Hi Hackerman, thanks for your help. How can I print this on the page instead of in a pop-up box?

Comment: @Beccas I've posted an answer below.

Comment: @atymic Thank you very much; how helpful! It works perfectly! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template/post, add the following for the javascript to populate with the scores:

```html
<span id="reviews">Loading reviews ...</span>
```

Then, you can use the following javascript to load the scores into that tag:

```js
const url = "https://api.yotpo.com/products/Q6IzQniPhEwgOfDx2C58uKPy5G2OgNnZtPpQpfWI/4379928772/bottomline";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    const data = json.response;
    const avg = data.bottomline["average_score"];
    const numReviews = data.bottomline["total_reviews"];
    const textContent = `This is based on ${numReviews} with an average score of ${avg}`;
    document.getElementById('reviews').innerHTML = textContent;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    alert("The reviews could not be loaded!");
    console.error(err.message);
  });
```

Js fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/s2zamerk/